# python coding from matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have this code in MATLAB and I am trying to convert it in Python.

```
A=[1,-0.75,0.25]

yc(1:45)=-2;
y(1:6)=0
u(1:6)=0
[lig,col]=size(A);


alpha(1)=1;
alpha(2)=A(2)-1;

if(col>2)
   for i=3:col
    alpha(i)=A(i)-A(i-1); 
   end ;
end;

alpha(col+1)=-A(col);
```

I don't know how to convert it in python thnx for helping me

Comment: you need to give it a shot with python, and come back with where you're stuck once you've gotten any code at all.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if your code would have been a minimal example of what you are trying to do. You are defining variables that are not even used. But here's a more or less literal translation. Note that you probably want to preallocate `alpha` (both in Matlab and Python)

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1.0, -.75, .25])

yc = -2 * np.ones(45)
y = np.zeros(6)
u = np.zeros(6)
col = A.size

alpha = np.array([1, A[1] - 1])

if col > 2:
    for i in range(2, col):
        alpha = np.append(alpha, A[i] - A[i-1])
        
alpha = np.append(alpha, -A[col-1])
```

Comment: when you create `y` and `u` you don't manage to create two separate objects, rather two references to the same array

Comment: @Aaron I wasn't sure what's the role of `y` and `u` here since they aren't used. If they aren't modified going forth, this works. But you are probably right that OP might intend them to be two different objects. I'll change the code just to be sure.